# LDAP : Cannot resolve group *** to gid : not found

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, ubuntu-10.04, openldap

During the step *User and Group Management* in LDAP installation I wrote the following command

```
sudo ldapadduser george example
```

and got this error

> Cannot resolve group example to gid : not found

Comment: Please, correct your English.

Also, please share your configs (/etc/nsswitch.conf, ldap configs) and your previous steps. I have no idea what is "d step User and Group Management"

Comment: i was trying to create a user

Answer (score 1):

You tried to add user george to the group example but this group doesn't exist (yet). See what groups exist or use the command `ldapaddgroup example` first (this should report an error if the group example already exists).

Comment: you r right. an error "Error adding group example to LDAP"

Comment: i tried it.what more to do ????

Comment: Enhance your question with more infos. I.e. what tutorial did you follow to install LDAP?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/openldap-server.html